# AS3 - drawPath() & winding overlaps producing strange behavior

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to draw multiple shapes in the same Sprite.graphics scope, and can't seem to find any reasonable solution to my problem.

Please keep in minde that I've been using the drawPath() method for a performance problem : I could use multiple shapes with blendmodes, but I'd like to avoid that and keep performances cost to the minimum.

I've been experimenting with the winding parameter of the drawPath() method, but one thing that I cannot understand, is how the winding direction is defined by Flash, so here is a first question before actually coming to the real problem : 
Are points coordinates taken in account ? Or is it the angle between the produces lines that define the direction ?

That being said, here is my actual problem : 
I want to draw a shape that is a projection from a rectangle on a line - think of a window and the light that passes through it that goes hit the floor.

[image]

To achieve that, I must take into account that the lightsource position can vary and have that kind of results :

[image]

Here on that second picture you can already see the problem I'm facing.
To draw my shape, I've been separately "drawing" (understand : placing the numbers in my coordinates vector) the different parts of my figure : the actual rectangle I want to project, the light projected from its left side, the light projected from its bottom side, and the light projected from its right side.

I've been trying to carefully keep the winding direction the same in every section, beginning from the top-left corner, but it seems something is wrong in my reasoning, since every time the center part overlaps with any side part, the shape is emptied there, and every time the two sides parts overlaps, the same happens.

As I'm writing that here, some revelation suddenly strike me, and now I guess that maybe **ALL my points** in my coordinates vector must be sorted in the same winding direction for my shape to work ?... (and not only the small parts I'm separately drawing in my mind ^^)

If I'm right (please correct me if I'm not, or if I've understood anything wrong ?...), that means I must either :

- sort my points to be placed in the correct winding direction (thing that might be complicated and could result in some strange drawed shape once provided to the drawing API ?...)
- only draw the shape from the most external points, depending on the shape's actual shape (thing that might be more complicated that I currently expect).

Could anyone here confirm or infirm my last suppositions, and give me a clue on what could be going on here and how to solve it ?...

Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Not sure about your specific question but wondering if you have read through the docs here already about controlling winding... might be helpful but perhaps you've already been through it http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS1EE3740D-F65C-43bf-9B12-74E34D7D1CBE.html

Comment: More precisely, `GraphicsPathWinding.NON_ZERO` is what you need to set for your fill style. Actually, I'd do what you want with two layers, top one containing light, and bottom one containing window. You will have to play with BlendMode's of them for desired effects.

Comment: Thanks for your answers both of you, but actually I've already been browsing through the doc and also using the GraphicsPathWinding.NON_ZERO parameter, but the result wont make what I want to... In the docs, nothing states how the winding direction is actually defined, it only says "order in which the renderer interprets the coordinates". But is that direction defined by the first 2 sets of coordinates, constantly redefined while parsing through the vector...? I'd prefer only use a single shape and not use BlendModes to achieve that, but I still can't have the exact shape as I'd like to...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have one shape composed out of three projector lines? Okay, you have determined the positions of two lower points, and you have 4 points of your window. You then construct a list like so:

- Two topmost points are always in the list, as you write that your light will always fall down out of the window. So, put 0 in command, window's upper left point coordinates into path, 1 into command (lineTo), window's upper right point into path.
- Now, if both of your floor points have X less than lower right angle of the window, you add the window's point into the path!
- Then you add rightmost floor point, then leftmost.
- Then, if both of your floor points have X greater than lower LEFT corner of the window, you add it to the list.

You're done. And you will no longer need 3 projections, you calculate only the bottommost one (it'll give you both points on the floor), and make your list. Should do. Please comment.

Comment: Aha yeah, didn't though of such a solution... I was so deeply thinking of a full shaping-solution I didn't tried anything else... even if it simpler ! I'm going to try that, I must force me not to always make the most "elegant" solution and rather go for the most effective one :-)

Comment: Thanks for that, now its working... I'd still want to know (mostly for educationnal purposes ^^) how the winding direction is calculated by Flash, but I've managed to do what I want... Thanks !